# Debian 8.5 (обновленный), может ли на сегодняшний день пользователь получить локальные привилегии через уязвимости ядра или компонентов ОС?

Tags: debian, уязвимости

**На сегодняшний день** может ли обычный пользователь получить **локальные привилегии через уязвимости ядра или компонентов Debian 8.5** (обновленный по 2018)? Можно ли этой сборке доверять? или уже есть известные дыры в этой сборке?

*uname -a: Linux adm223 3.16.0-5-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.51-3+deb8u1 (2018-01-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux*

Answer (score 1):

Или debian 8.5 или обновлённый, но уже debian 8.10. Что-то одно, но не оба сразу. Хотя это не мешает обновить ядро независимо от системы, репозиторий-то один и тот же.

Информацию об обнаруженных уязвимостях публикуют в специальном списке рассылок [debian-security-announce](https://lists.debian.org/debian-security-announce/)

В целом про обновления безопасности в `debian` можно начать читать с [соответствующего раздела](https://www.debian.org/security/) сайта проекта.

`Debian Jessie (8)` на данный момент является [`oldstable`](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianOldStable) веткой, поддержка длится 1 год с релиза нового `stable`. То есть обычная поддержка будет прекращена в июне 2018 года. Однако архитектуры `i386`, `amd64`, `armel` и `armhf` попадают под [`LTS` поддержку](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS). Если у вас используются соответствующие репозитории - то вы сможете получать обновления безопасности до апреля 2020 года.